# my ubuntu terminal seems to be fixed in the sudo theme, how to restore the terminal to default theme

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, themes, sudo, su

I ran the command `sudo su` and enter my password. Then, my terminal's font color turn to white and bold text was deactivated (mode which i call the sudo theme). But when I run the command `exit` my terminal keep the sudo theme even when I am out of the super user mode.

[My user in the terminal have neither bold text nor color, how i do fix that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5cSJ.png)

Comment: Have you tried `reset`?

Comment: yes but it didn't work